# How to proof by natural number case analysis in Coq?

Tags: coq

I am stucked by a proof using coq. I have the following definitions:

```
Require Import List.
Require Import Nat.

Fixpoint Inb(x: nat) (A: list nat) :=
 match A with
 | nil => false
 | h :: t => if h =? x then true else (Inb x t)
 end.

Definition In (x: nat) (A: list nat) := 
  Inb x A = true.
```

Then I want to proof the theorem:

```
Theorem inside_thm: forall x, In x (3::4::nil) -> x = 3 \/ x = 4.
```

However, I got stucked and no idea of how can I proof it.

Could you please give me a guide and write an example to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, you may start with a few helpful lemmas about `In`.

```
Lemma In1 x y l : In x (y::l) <-> y = x \/ In x l. 
  Proof.    
   unfold In;  simpl; rewrite <- PeanoNat.Nat.eqb_eq. 
    case (y =? x).  
     - split;  auto. 
     - split.
       + auto. 
       + destruct 1; [discriminate | auto]. 
Qed.

Lemma In2 x : ~ In x nil. 
Proof. 
 discriminate. 
Qed.
```

Then your lemma can be easily proved.

```
Theorem inside_thm: forall x, In x (3::4::nil) -> x = 3 \/ x = 4.
Proof.
  intros x H; rewrite In1 in H. 
  (* ... *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, very specific, approach to proving this particular theorem could be to:

1. first, assume that `x = 3` and then show, in that case, that the statement is trivially true, after rewriting everywhere `x` by 3;
2. now, under the hypothesis that `x` is not equalt to 3, do the same, assuming now that `x = 4`;
3. finally, show that, if `x` is neither 3 nor 4, the statement remains valid, since, by expanding the definitions of `In` and `Inb`, you can show that all the tests in the Coq-generated `if` statement are false (Coq is able to unroll all the calls to `Inb`, since the list argument is a constant in your case), yielding `false = true` as an hypothesis in the goal, which makes it trivially true.

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about how natural numbers and booleans work in Coq. The whole difficulty with boolean conditionals is that you have to establish **constructively** whether or not the conditional holds in order to determine the value of the expression. Likewise, a hallmark of the inductive **construction** of natural numbers is that you can determine (constructively) whether or not a natural number is 0, whether it is 1, whether it is 2, whether it is 3, etc., and you have to use such a chain of reasoning in order to unwind the boolean expression `In x (3::4::nil)` into an outcome like `x = 3 ∨ x = 4`.

With all that said, your proof can be done very simply by repeatedly testing whether `x` is 0, 1, 2, 3, ... until the proof finishes. One convenient idiom for doing so is

```
Theorem inside_thm: forall x, In x (3::4::nil) -> x = 3 \/ x = 4.
Proof. intros; repeat (destruct x; try intuition discriminate). Qed.
```

By contrast, if you're using the built-in `List.In` which is defined with propositional expressions, then the corresponding theorem is trivial enough for Coq to figure out by itself:

```
Theorem inside_thm2 : forall x, List.In x (3::4::nil) -> x = 3 \/ x = 4.
Proof. firstorder. Qed.
```